# What is considered game-specific hardware (and my personal example)?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

In the help guide for the site, it says that questions can be about "**Game-specific hardware and utilities**". *What is encompassed in that topic, and what kind of subjects are not considered a part of that topic?*

I wanted to ask a question about game framerate, and whether the human eye / brain can discern extremely high framerate. I feel it could or could not be acceptable, so to save the embarrassment of having a question closed, and to help others, I wanted to ask here first. If not, where should I direct my question to get an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be off-topic here because it's about human sensory systems, not about actually about hardware. That sounds like it might be on-topic for [biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/).

"Game-specific hardware" means any hardware that is specific to gaming. This can be a fuzzy line sometimes, but it helps to consider whether *gamers* specifically would be the experts on a question, or whether someone else woudl be. For example, troubleshooting a PC's disc drive because it's not reading a game disc is *not* gaming-specific, while troubleshooting a disc drive on an Xbox is. Why? Because the latter is something gamers are experts on (sadly), while the misbehaving PC disc drive is something that expert computer users will be best able to help with.

Comment: Well it would be formatted specifically to be about how important framerate is to playing a game. Considering gamers obsess over how fast they can run games I figure it would be an area of expertise. It wasn't meant to be a question about our body, that's just a consequence of the topic.

Comment: @MapCavalier I can only really answer based on what you wrote above. It might be a different answer if it was written differently. If you're considering whether a rewritten version of what you're thinking of would be acceptable, or want help, consider asking on [chat] for opinions and help with wording.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks, I'll go for that.

Answer (score 4):

Some of your question may already be answered here:

[Why do video game framerates need to be so much higher than TV and cinema framerates?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25465/why-do-video-game-framerates-need-to-be-so-much-higher-than-tv-and-cinema-framer)

There are some high quality answers there about why the 16/24/60 fps standards exist, what the human eye can discern, and how a low/high fps setting can affect gameplay and input

Comment: Thanks for that, this is really helpful. I have to give the answer to SevenSidedDie though, since I was asking about the validity of questions like mine on Arquade. Regardless I really appreciate the post, thanks c:

Comment: @MapCavalier - That's ok, glad I could help